# Has someone a workaround to activate 2 or multiple dropdowns with Materialize Framework?

Tags: jquery, dropdown, materialize

I'm trying to have to mutiple dropdowns elements in Materialize. I found out that it doesn't work, but there is a workaround stated here by singhshash:

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2621

my problem is I can't activate dropdown accessing id='btndropdown1', but it is the only ID with this specific name. Has anyone a workaround other that the solution stated above?

```
<a id='btndropdown1' class='dropdown-trigger' href="#" data-target='dropdown1'>
  <div class="col s2 m3">
    <div class="card red darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title center">Heizen</span>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <i class="material-icons large white-text">hot_tub</i>
      </div>

      <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content red darken-1'>
        <li ><a href="#!" class="black-text">Heizgeräte</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Ex-Heizgeräte</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Heizgebläse</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a  id='btndropdown2' class='dropdown-trigger' href="#" data-target='dropdown2'>
  <div class="col s2 m2">
    <div class="card cyan darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title center">Filterlüfter</span>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <i class="material-icons large white-text">view_headline</i>
      </div>
      <ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content cyan'>
        <li ><a href="#!" class="black-text">Filterlüfter</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Outdoor-Filterlüfter</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Dach-Filterlüfter</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Lüftereinschub</a></li>
        <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
        <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Einbaulüfter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btndropdown1').dropdown();
    $('#btndropdown2').dropdown();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you want to add two drop-down on single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown not work because you added dropdown (`<ul>` tag) inside `<a>` tag.

If you move it outside of `<a>`, problem will solve.

```
<a id='btndropdown1' class='dropdown-trigger' href="#" data-target='dropdown1'>
  <div class="col s2 m3">
    <div class="card red darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title center">Heizen</span>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <i class="material-icons large white-text">hot_tub</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content red darken-1'>
  <li ><a href="#!" class="black-text">Heizgeräte</a></li>
  <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
  <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Ex-Heizgeräte</a></li>
  <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
  <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Heizgebläse</a></li>
</ul>
<a  id='btndropdown2' class='dropdown-trigger' href="#" data-target='dropdown2'>
  <div class="col s2 m2">
    <div class="card cyan darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title center">Filterlüfter</span>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <i class="material-icons large white-text">view_headline</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content cyan'>
   <li ><a href="#!" class="black-text">Filterlüfter</a></li>
   <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
   <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Outdoor-Filterlüfter</a></li>
   <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
   <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Dach-Filterlüfter</a></li>
   <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
   <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Lüftereinschub</a></li>
   <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
   <li><a href="#!" class="black-text">Einbaulüfter</a></li>
 </ul>
```

you can see solution here : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/s8cfa0oh)

Comment: this helped me a lot, but an other issue appeared since this whole thing is wrapped inside an <div class="row"> tag the dropdown content shows up at the right corner of the page, but I want it to show up exactly as normal dropdown like materialize. I tried the grid sollution but that also puts the dropdown content right to the card. Do you know what can be done about this?

Comment: you mean that want to have a smaller width in your dropdown?

Comment: no I mean, that the dropdown content is showing right to the element and not inside the element

Comment: could you show me an example that is similar you think?

Comment: you can place the html code above that you answerded with inside <div class="row">answer code frome above </div> and you will see that the dropdown is misplaced on the side and not at element.

Comment: you can put `<ul>` and `<a>` tags inside of `<div class="row"><div class"col ...` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/s8cfa0oh/26/

Comment: almost but I meant to wrap the whole thing in a row class, like this:https://jsfiddle.net/9oy67mv5/2/

Comment: thank you very much for your patience, you solved my problems

Comment: I'm happy for this